# LUA indexed table access via named constants

Tags: lua, lua-table, magic-constants

I am using LUA as embedded language on a µC project, so the ressources are limited. To save some cycles and memory I do always only indexed based table access (table[1]) instead og hash-based access (table.someMeaning = 1). This saves a lot of memory.

The clear drawback of this is approach are the magic numbers thrughtout the code.

A Cpp-like preprocessor would help here to replace the number with named-constants.

Is there a good way to achieve this?
A preprocessor in LUA itself, loading the script and editing the chunk and then loading it would be a variant, but I think this exhausts the ressources in the first place ...

Comment: You could use `GNU M4`, this is a general purpose preprocessor, quite easy to use and very suitable to your use-case. Another solution could be to write a small script replacing your TOKENS with successive `sed` text substitutions.

Comment: The first example of `GNU M4` is interesting https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5594#:~:text=The%20basic%20tool%20of%20m4%20is%20the%20macro.,surround%20a%20single%20word%20they%20inhibit%20macro%20expansion.

Comment: Then the next question for the m4 way: how to embed the m4 definitions into the lua script itself (more like using cpp)

Comment: I think the easiest way is to use the cpp for lua ;-)

Comment: That's probably also a good idea, as you don't need another tool.

Comment: Actually, there are also `Lua` general-purpose preprocessors, for example that one http://lua-users.org/wiki/SlightlyLessSimpleLuaPreprocessor

Comment: You can write a preprocessor for this easily using my token processor: https://web.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#ltokenp

Comment: See also http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-02/msg00881.html

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a simple solution: write your own preprocessor in `Lua`!
It's probably the most easy thing to do.

First, define your symbols globally:

```
MySymbols = {
  FIELD_1 = 1,
  FIELD_2 = 2,
  FIELD_3 = 3,
}
```

Then you write your `preprocessing` function, which basically just replace the strings from `MySymbols` by their value.

```
function Preprocess (FilenameIn, FilenameOut)
  local FileIn     = io.open(FilenameIn, "r")
  local FileString = FileIn:read("*a") 

  for Name, Value in pairs(MySymbols) do
    FileString = FileString:gsub(Name, Value)
  end

  FileIn:close()

  local FileOut = io.open(FilenameOut, "w")
  FileOut:write(FileString)
  FileOut:close()
end
```

Then, if you try with this input file `test.txt`:

```
TEST FIELD_1
TEST FIELD_2
TEST FIELD_3
```

And call the following function:

```
Preprocess("test.txt", "test-out.lua")
```

You will get the fantastic output file:

```
TEST  1
TEST  2
TEST  3
```

I let you the joy to integrate it with your scripts/toolchain.

If you want to avoid attributing the number manually, you could just add a wonderful closure:

```
function MakeCounter ()
  local Count = 0
  return function ()
    Count = Count + 1
    return Count
  end
end

NewField = MakeCounter()

MySymbols = {
  FIELD_1 = NewField(),
  FIELD_2 = NewField(),
  FIELD_3 = NewField()
}
```

Comment: This solution will replace names inside strings, which may or not be what you want.

Comment: You are correct, but for real-world usage for his micro-controller, this solution is pretty good. You don't do lot of string management in a micro-controller... He just need to find a name, probably with upper case and there will not be any name collision.

Comment: Sadly the whole LUA sourcecode does not fit into µC to be replaced on the µC